# Is it safe to use zero as second index in accessing Eigen::VectorXd?

Tags: c++, eigen

`Eigen::VectorXd` has an `Scalar operator()(Index i)` which returns the coefficient at the index `i` in the vector. However, since `Eigen::VectorXd` is a special type of an `Eigen::Matrix`, i.e. of type `Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;`, there is also an `Scalar operator()(Index i, Index j)`.

**Question:**

Can I assume that it is safe (i.e. no undefined behaviour) to use the second version if I set `j` to zero? In other words, is the code below OK?

```
Eigen::VectorXd v(4);
v << 1, 2, 3, 4;
std::cout << v(2, 0); // displays 3
```

It looks like it's OK, there are no failed assertions or warnings when compiled in debug mode with all warnings on, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: As I said I tried, but if there is some quirky UB trying is not gonna make you certain the code is OK.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. By your wording, it made it sound like you compiled but didn't run it.

Comment: @mascoj No worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe as long as `v` is a column vector, whereas using `v(i)` works for both column and row vectors, e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T &v) {
  v(2);   // OK
  v(2,0); // -> out of bounds runtime assertion
}
MatrixXd mat(10,10);
foo(mat.row(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll expound upon @ggaels [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014588/2899559). If you look at the `operator()` definitions in DenseCoeffsBase.h (I'm quoting 3.2.10) you'll see that they both call `coeff` (or `coeffRef`)

```
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CoeffReturnType operator()(Index row, Index col) const
{
  eigen_assert(row >= 0 && row < rows()
      && col >= 0 && col < cols());
  return derived().coeff(row, col);
}

EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CoeffReturnType
operator()(Index index) const
{
  eigen_assert(index >= 0 && index < size());
  return derived().coeff(index);
}
```

Looking at the definitions of coeffRef in PlainObjectBase.h we see that the offset is calculated simply:

```
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Scalar& coeffRef(Index rowId, Index colId)
{
  if(Flags & RowMajorBit)
    return m_storage.data()[colId + rowId * m_storage.cols()];
  else // column-major
    return m_storage.data()[rowId + colId * m_storage.rows()];
}

EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Scalar& coeffRef(Index index)
{
  return m_storage.data()[index];
}
```

So in the case of a row vector, you would have to write `v(0,2)` to avoid possible assertions failures/out of bounds errors.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, it's indeed reassuring.